# Error received when using an API GET request, with JSON and Python

Tags: python, json, api, rest, get

I'm getting an error trying to do an API get request, when using JSON RESTful services and Python3. Any help is appreciated. I'm supposed to use API instructions from this website https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/vulnerabilities#. I already have the CVE number, it's listed in my URL below.

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/CVE-2021-40463/1.0/').json()

print (response)
```

---

```
File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/UT_Code/UT_Homework.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = requests.get('https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/CVE-2021-40463/1.0/').json()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Did you open the url in the browser? It does not return JSON.

Comment: That is confusing. I get nothing. The website strictly says it uses JSON.

Comment: I think you want to access `https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/CVE-2021-40463/`

Comment: have you read the documentation? clearly, your get request is wrong. you need to give the link and then parameters and use approipriate api

Comment: @sahasrara62 apologies - clearly didn't understand the instructions. I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is wrong. Use

```
https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/CVE-2021-40463/
```

full code:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/CVE-2021-40463')
data = response.json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Hi sadly, I just didn't enter URL correctly. Code is working on my end. One last question, can you give me tips on how to use PARAMETERS in my code so that it prints better in my terminal? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my code. As an alternative - use `pprint.pprint`. Not sure what you mean by _use PARAMETERS_